# Assembly code for C++ virtual function call in perf report?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86-64, disassembly, perf

I'm doing some profiling for virtual function call performance and when read the perf report, I got this:

```
mov (%rbx),%rdi   # move "this" pointer to %rdi
mov (%rdi),%rax   # move vtable pointer to %rax
mov %rbp,%rsi     # move first virtual function parameter to %rsi
callq *38         # absolute address call? why?
```

It calls virtual function via `callq *38`, I've tried to search AT&T assembly syntax manual and find out this is an absolute address function call which jumps to absolute address `38`, my question is why it uses absolute address here instead of getting the address from `vtable` entries(via `%rax`)?

I'm using perf version 4.15.18, and objdump shows me：

```
48 8b 3b      mov  (%rbx),%rdi
48 8b 07      mov  (%rdi),%rax
48 89 ee      mov  %rbp,%rsi
ff 50 38      callq *0x38(%rax)
48 83 c3 08   add %0x8,%rbx
```

Example code to reproduce the problem under my test environment:

```c++
#include <vector>
struct A {
    virtual int v1(int x) {
        return x+1;
    }

    virtual int v2(int x) {
        return x+2;
    }

    virtual int v3(int x) {
        return x+3;
    }
};

struct B:A {
    int v3(int x) override {
        return x+4;
    }
};

struct C:A {
    int v2(int x) override {
        return x+5;
    }
};

int main(){
    B b;
    C c;
    std::vector<A*> vs = {&b, &c};
    int t = 0;
    while (true) {
        t = vs[0]->v3(t);
        t = vs[1]->v3(t);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with g++ 7.5.0 via `g++ test.cc -O3`, perf 4.15.18 shows:

```
...
mov %eax,%esi
mov (%rbx),%rdi
mov (%rdi),%rdx
callq *10
mov 0x8(%rbx),%rdi
mov %eax,%esi
mov (%rdi),%rdx
callq *10
jmp 68
...
```

objdump shows:

```
89 c6         mov %eax,%esi
48 8b 3b      mov (%rbx),%rdi
48 8b 17      mov (%rdi),rdx
ff 52 10      callq *0x10(%rdx)
48 8b 7b 08   mov 0x8(%rbx),%rdi
89 c6         mov %eax,%esi
48 8b 17      mov (%rdi),rdx
ff 52 10      callq *0x10(%rdx)
```

Comment: after adding -Mintel option for perf report, I got "call QWORD PTR [rax+0x38]", which makes sense now. I don't know why it's an absolute address funcion call in AT&T assembly mode

Comment: `callq *38` would actually load a new RIP from absolute address 38.  Not jump to (set RIP to) 38.  It's an indirect call (hence the `*`) with a memory source operand, not direct.  Can you post the relevant machine code?  This seems like a bug in your version of binutils, assuming perf uses that for disassembly.  Or a corrupt file or something.  `callq *38` is definitely not a sane instruction to ever find in compiler-generated code; Linux's default `mmap_min_address` is 64KiB, `38` is in the same page as a NULL pointer, and we want NULL deref to always fault.

Comment: What perf version?  Does `objdump -d` disassemble it correctly to a sane `call *0x38(%rax)`?  Perhaps a bug in `perf` is stepping on some memory and messing up binutils disassembly.  `call *0x38(%rax)` (opcode + modrm + disp8 = 3 bytes) would be a different instruction-length from `call *38` (opcode + modrm + sib + disp32 = 7 bytes, with SIB being required to encode an absolute instead of RIP-relative address with no register) so probably less likely that perf is corrupting machine-code data it feeds to the disassembler functions.

Comment: [edit] your question with that info an `objdump` output, don't try to post it in comments because they don't allow formatting.

Comment: 4.15 is fairly old; if you can make a [mcve] of something you can compile/run (or assemble and run for compiler-generated asm) and consistently get that broken report with, other people could test an up to date perf and see if it's still buggy.

Comment: @PeterCordes I've appended the example code

Comment: I get `call   *0x10(%rax)` with my perf 5.16, so either it's fixed, or random chance made it not happen there.  I'd normally use `perf report -Mintel` anyway, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks, I'll try to update my perf and check the results